# Can i also put a scope through the filter?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, database, parsing

i made a taskfilter and i need to edit the tekst of the titel if another button is selected, i tried a scope but that doen't work do you guys know of mayby somethiing else if scope does not works?

the rule that i am talking about it $scope,infotitel, i tried also to put scope function in the filter above but that also does not work.

heres my filter code

> $scope.infoTitel = 'completed'; ------------- i put this in every if statement because on click it filters out the tasks into done or not but the scope i want to use to show the tekst completted etcc in html

```
return function(values, taskCompleted) {

  // filter
  return values.filter(function(value){
    if(taskCompleted === 1) {
                $scope.infoTitel = 'completed';
        return value.completed;
    }
    else if(taskCompleted === 2){
                $scope.infoTitel = 'all';
        return true;
    }
            else if(taskCompleted === 3){
                $scope.infoTitel = 'deadline missed';
        return value.dateExpired;
    }
            // initially don't filter
            else if(!value.completed && !value.dateExpired){
                $scope.infoTitel = 'to do';
                return value;
            }

    //return $sce.trustAsHtml(output); voor als html verandert

  });
};
```

this is the part where the buttons are

```
<div class="mini-nav">
            <a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilter = 3" ng-class="{'active' : taskfilter == 3}">
                <span>deadline missed</span>.
            </a>
            <a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilter = 2" ng-class="{'active' : taskfilter == 2}">
                <span>show all </span>.
            </a>
            <a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilter = 1" ng-class="{'active' : taskfilter == 1}">
                <span>show completed</span>.
            </a>

            <a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilter = 0" ng-class="{'active' : taskfilter == 0}" ng-init="">
                <span>to do</span>.
            </a>
        </div>
```

this is the html, the first line is where i want to display it

> li ng-repeat="todo in tasks | filterTask:taskfilter " ng-class="getCSSClass(todo)" ------------- the filterTask is the custom filter for wher i want to put the scope tekst in it so the first piece of code.
>
> ## {{ infoTitel }} by family
>
> ----------- this is where i want the tekst

```
<h1>{{ infoTitel }} by family</h1>

    <div id="main" style="display: block;">
        <ul id="todo-list" class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="todo in tasks | filterTask:taskfilter " ng-class="getCSSClass(todo)" >
                <div class="view" ng-keyup="editTodo()">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleTodo(todo)" class="check-done-{{todo.completed}}"  ng-hide= "todo.dateExpired "/>
                    <span class="done-{{todo.completed}}">{{todo.task}} </span>
                    <p ng-show="todo.completed">completed by: {{ todo.completedBy.name }} </p>
                    <p ng-show="todo.completed">date completed : {{ todo.dateCompleted | date : "MMM d, y h:mm a" }}</p>
                    <p ng-hide="todo.completed" ng-if= " !todo.dateExpired ">task deadline : {{ todo.timeToDeadline || "no deadline" | date : "MMM d, y h:mm"  }}</p>
                    <p ng-hide="todo.completed" ng-if= " todo.dateExpired ">deadline missed on {{ todo.dateExpiration | date : "MMM d, y h:mm a"}}</p>
                    <div class="bar-holder" ng-show="todo.percentage || todo.percentage == 0"  ng-if="!todo.completed " >
                      <div class="bar" style="width: {{todo.percentage}}%;" ></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input class="edit" type="text" ng-model="todo.text" ng-keyup="editOnEnter(todo)" />
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Please share some fiddle or at least update your question including the entire  directive code and the html where you use it

Comment: i updated the tekst i think it clearifies where i use the code in my html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem i could just change the tekst within the buttons, added another click and added the tekst directly in there so it dsplays on the place of

## {{ infoTitel }} by family

```
<div class="mini-nav">
            <a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilter = 'missed'; infoTitel = 'Deadline missed'" ng-class="{'active' : taskfilter == 'missed'}">
                <span>deadline missed</span>
            </a>
            <a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilter = 'all'; infoTitel = 'All'" ng-class="{'active' : taskfilter == 'all'}">
                <span>show all </span>
            </a>
            <a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilter = 'completed'; infoTitel = 'Completed'" ng-class="{'active' : taskfilter == 'completed'}">
                <span>show completed</span>
            </a>
            <a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilter = 'todo'; infoTitel = 'To do'" ng-class="{'active' : taskfilter == 'todo'}" ng-init="">
                <span>to do</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

ps: changed the 3,2,1,0 filternames in to missed,all, completed and todo for better understanding of filter